# Is on demand delivery of a flutter package possible using ondemand feature?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, dynamic-feature-module, flutter-platform-channel

I need to add an native library in existing flutter app. I have made a package of it having some platform channel code along with library but I don't want to increase app size so is there any way possible to deploy that complete package using on demand feature on Android.

Comment: Related: [How to dynamically load a compiled native library into an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56046513/295004)